# Add in a new column that appends all uppercase words in a phrase to a list per row

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
      Date                          Sentence                                      Text              Verified
_               
0   2020-01-18 00:00:00 LUKE Diamond is a famous                         Updates · BREAKING News    False
1   2020-01-18 00:00:00 Blog - TASTY YUMMIES                             Brush with ...             False
2   2020-01-18 00:00:00 ACNE Alternative Remedies: Manuka HONEY          Learn more from WEBMD      False
3   2020-01-18 00:00:00 Looking back at 10 YEARS                         As the LOCAL community     False
```

I would like select words in upper case that might be in Sentence or in Text (I would like to save these results into two separate columns, rows by rows).

```
      Date                          Sentence                                      Text              Verified    CS                            CT
_               
0   2020-01-18 00:00:00 LUKE Diamond is a famous                         Updates · BREAKING News    False     ['LUKE']               ['BREAKING']
1   2020-01-18 00:00:00 Blog - TASTY YUMMIES                             Brush with ...             False    ['TASTY', 'YUMMIES']            []
2   2020-01-18 00:00:00 ACNE Alternative Remedies: Manuka HONEY          Learn more from WEBMD      False      ['ACNE','HONEY']      ['WEBMD']
3   2020-01-18 00:00:00 Looking back at 10 YEARS                         As the LOCAL community     False      ['YEARS']             ['LOCAL']
```

I have tried as follows (this should generate a list of words in upper cases, rows by rows), but I am getting the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` in caps.
Could you please tell me what is not working and how I can get the expected output? Many thanks.

```
import re

def s_l(file):
    s = []

    for c in file['Sentence'].tolist(): 
        caps = re.findall('([A-Z]+(?:(?!\s?[A-Z][a-z])\s?[A-Z])+)', c)
        s.append(caps)
    for c in file['Text'].tolist(): 
        caps = re.findall('([A-Z]+(?:(?!\s?[A-Z][a-z])\s?[A-Z])+)', c)
        s.append(caps)

    file['CS'] = pd.Series(s)
    s = [x for x in s if x != [] and len(x)>1]
    file['CT'] = pd.Series(s)
    s = [x for x in s if x != [] and len(x)>1]

    return file, s

s_df, s =s_l(df)
```

I think I am all wrongly considering a list of words, so probably I should add another list (not only s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list comprehension object `m` that compares values to `.upper()` to get all uppercase letters and `.isalpha()` to make sure you are not bringing in strings / numbers where `.upper()` doesn't do anything to them. Then, simply create new columns that utilize the list comprehension with `.apply(m)`

```
m = lambda x: [y for y in str(x).split(' ') if y.upper() == y and y.isalpha()]
df['CS'] = df['Sentence'].apply(m)
df['CT'] = df['Text'].apply(m)
```

output:

```
    Date                          Sentence                                      Text              Verified    CS                            CT               
0   2020-01-18 00:00:00 LUKE Diamond is a famous                         Updates · BREAKING News    False     ['LUKE']               ['BREAKING']
1   2020-01-18 00:00:00 Blog - TASTY YUMMIES                             Brush with ...             False    ['TASTY', 'YUMMIES']            []
2   2020-01-18 00:00:00 ACNE Alternative Remedies: Manuka HONEY          Learn more from WEBMD      False      ['ACNE','HONEY']      ['WEBMD']
3   2020-01-18 00:00:00 Looking back at 10 YEARS                         As the LOCAL community     False      ['YEARS']             ['LOCAL']
```

Comment: His David. I received this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: prior to the code in my answer, does doing this help? `df['Sentence'] =  df['Sentence'].astype(str)` and `df['Text'] = df['Text'].astype(str)`  EDIT: Alternatively see my updated answer with `str(x).split(' ')` instead of `x.split(' ')`

Answer (score 3):

You can `regex` with `findall`

```
df['CS'] = df.Sentence.str.findall('\\b[A-Z]+\\b')
```

Output

```
df['CS']

0              [LUKE]
1    [TASTY, YUMMIES]
2       [ACNE, HONEY]
3             [YEARS]
```

Comment: some words are not added in the new column, as not detected. How could I include them? For example, I have only one word in Sentence in upper case, GRAZIA, which was not found

Comment: Thank you YOBEN_S. The same word was detected using David's answer

Comment: @still_learning ` df.Sentence.fillna('').astype(str).str.findall('\\b[A-Z]+\\b')`

Comment: @YOBEN_S:  I found that this works:  `df.Sentence.fillna('').str.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b')`  .  Is it significantly different without the astype(str) ?